# Alter behaviour of jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog defined with jQuery UI in this way:

```
this.dialog = $.dialog({
    title: 'Title',
    open: function () {
        //do something
    },
    close: function () {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

How can I at a later point in my code override the behaviour of the `close` method?

Comment: You should explain exactly what you want to do, close is close, I assume you want to do something else when the close button is pressed, like what exactly ??

Comment: @LawrenceEdel I want to apply some custom logic (i.e. show a confirmation alert before closing) when the user clicks the close button, and based on some condition, actually call or not the original `close` method

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call **dialogclose** event to close a dialog later.

```
$('div#dialogbox').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
     // your code goes here.
 });
```

Comment: To be clear, this is attaching an event handler, which will be called when the dialog is closed.

Comment: using this approach, is it possible to avoid the code in the original `close` method to be called?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the `dialogbeforeclose` event.

```
this.dialog.on('dialogbeforeclose', function() {
     // some code
});
```

If I return `false` from the callback, the `close` method is not run.